# Python how to apply classes correctly

Tags: python, class

I wrote the following class and program:

```
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x_coordinate = x
        self.y_coordinate = y

class CoordinatRow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.coordinaterow = []

    def add_coordinaterow(self, coordinate):
        self.coordinaterow.append(coordinate)

    def weave(self,other):
        lijst = []
        for i in range(len(self.coordinaterow)):
            lijst.append(self.coordinaterow[i])
            lijst.append(other.row[i]) 
        coordinaterow = lijst
        print coordinaterow
```

program:

```
from Coordinates import Coordinate, CoordinatRow
from ipy_lib import file_input

'''functies'''

def split_and_add(invoer):
    rij = invoer.split('=')
    for line in rij:
        process_row(line)  

def process_row(line):
    temp_coordinate_row = CoordinatRow()
    rij = line.split()
    for coordinate in rij:
        coor = process_coordinate(coordinate)
        temp_coordinate_row.add_coordinaterow(coor)
    return temp_coordinate_row

def process_coordinate(coordinate):
    idunno = coordinate.split(',')
    return Coordinate(int(idunno[0]),int(idunno[1]))

'''programma'''
bestand = file_input()
split_and_add(bestand)
rows = split_and_add(bestand)
for row in rows:
    row.weave(row)
```

The input looks as follows:

```
5,4 4,5 8,7=6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3=7,6=9,8=5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4
```

Ech row is seprated by an `=`. I want to weave each row with the next row like this:

```
5.4, 4.5, 8.7 weave with 6.3, 3.2, 9.6, 4.3
5.4, 6.3, 4.5, 3.2, 8.7, 9.6, 4.3
```

and the the next row into this new row.

The problem lies in the way I apply my classes I think. I am getting this error:

```
for row in rows:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: The problem is you are not returning anything from `split_and_add` thus rows is None

Comment: I think you want `yield process_row(line)` in the `split_and_add` function.  Otherwise you are returning `None`

Comment: how could i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd prefer not to use yield

```
def split_and_add(invoer):
    rij = invoer.split('=')
    rows = []
    for line in rij:
        rows.append(process_row(line))
    return rows
```

For your second problem you may want to do something like this:

```
for row in range(0,len(rows)-1):
    rows[row].weave(rows[row+1])
```

Comment: This works, but how would I then take each seperate object and weave it with the next, using my weave method?

Comment: Updated my answer with what I think you want.

Comment: Yes exactly. Only problem i get now is this error: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: If you print out rows what do you get?

Comment: [<Coordinates.CoordinatRow object at 0x02120910>, <Coordinates.CoordinatRow object at 0x021209D0>, <Coordinates.CoordinatRow object at 0x02125250>, <Coordinates.CoordinatRow object at 0x02125470>, <Coordinates.CoordinatRow object at 0x02125710>]

Comment: Fixed the issue it was my dumb fault

Answer (score 3):

```
def split_and_add(invoer):
    rij = invoer.split('=')
    for line in rij:
        yield process_row(line)
```

Comment: Like GWW said, add a yield statement so split_and_add is turned into a generator and can return your rows

Comment: And how can i take each seperate row and use my weave method in my class to weave it with the next one ?

Comment: In your code you apply weave to the row itself, not the next one, don't you ?

Comment: Yes, but this leads to an error: lijst.append(self.row[i])
AttributeError: 'CoordinatRow' object has no attribute 'row'. What i would like is that each row is woven into the next one like in the example in the thread